# Pattern matching on values of compound types - is it a compiler bug?

Tags: scala, scalac

I've stumbled upon a bit of a mysterious (at least to me) compiler behaviour when attempting to pattern match values with compound types, that I suspect might be a compiler bug. Before filing a bug report though, I would be glad if someone more knowledgeable than me could have a look at this and maybe provide some bit of explanation for what is going on.

We start with a little hierarchy of traits and case classes:

```
sealed trait A
case class A1() extends A
case class A2() extends A

sealed trait B
```

And we want to operate on values of compound type: `A with B`

```
val a1: A with B = new A1() with B
val a2: A with B = new A2() with B
val as: Seq[A with B] = Seq(a1, a2)
```

First, I've tried to pattern match using case class extractors:

```
Seq(a1, a2) foreach {
  case A1() => println("a1")
  case A2() => println("a2")
}
```

The above fails to compile due to type mismatch:

```
<console>:21: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : A1
 required: A with B
         case A1() => println("a1")
              ^
<console>:22: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : A2
 required: A with B
         case A2() => println("a2")
              ^
```

Second, I've replaced extractor usage with instance type matching:

```
as foreach {
  case _: A1 => println("a1")
  case _: A2 => println("a2")
}
```

The above does compile and *does* indeed work, printing "a1" and "a2" to the screen, but emits an erroneous warning about unreachable code:

```
<console>:23: warning: unreachable code
         case _: A2 => println("a2")
```

Surprisingly, making `A` not `sealed` gets rid of the warning (although the first pattern match still doesn't compile).

So, here come the questions:

1. Should the first pattern match compile? If not, then why exactly?
2. Is the warning emitted for the second pattern match plain wrong or have I just been lucky and there *are* cases when this match could take a wrong branch?
3. Should I file a bug report or maybe it's a long known issue I've just missed?

I've tested it on `2.11.7` and `2.11.8`.

Comment: It works if you make your `Seq` a `Seq[A]`: `val as: Seq[A] = Seq(a1, a2)`, then `as foreach { ... }`. Yours probably doesn't work because `A1` and `A2` are not subtypes of `A with B` (the element type of your `Seq`), so the pattern matcher thinks the match cannot work.

Comment: [Paragraph 8.4](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-expressions) of the Scala lang spec explains exactly how it should work, but it takes some time to read and understand this.

Comment: Yes, right, dropping `B` from the type before matching makes both the matches compile and succeed. I'm currently using `asInstanceOf[A]` before `match` in my actual code as a workaround.

Comment: `asInstanceOf[A]` is a cast, which is not type-safe; do that only if you really don't have a better, type-safe way to fix this.

Comment: In this case `asInstanceOf[A]` does not compromise type safety - it's statically verified by the compiler, that at a point of the cast, values have type `A with B`, so the cast here in practice just drops the `with B` part.